# Converting a series to a Riemann sum,

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, riemann-sum

I am manipulating a series and have gotten this far:

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{m=1}^n \frac {(\frac{m}{n})^{p-1}}{1+ (\frac{m}{n})^p} \frac{1}{n}$$

I want to now say that this is a Riemann sum, which corresponds to the Riemann integral

$$ \int_0^1 \frac {x^{p-1}}{1+x^p}dx$$

which evaluates to ln(2)/p -- the answer I am looking for.

Have I converted to the integral correctly?

My concerns are:  I just relabeled the discrete variable ($m/n$) as a continuous variable $x$.  Also I converted the $1/n$ interval length to $dx$ -- this part I am ok with, just from checking the definition of Riemann integral and knowing that I have to let mesh($p$) = supremum of sub-interval lengths go to zero.

So, I sort of did it blindly but I would like to know what are the rules that I may have missed?  E.g., does the variable ($m/n$) also have some size limits to adhere to?  Does ($m/n$) have to be small?

Thanks,

EDIT: The main concern really is:  in past problems, I converted to Riemann integrals that did *not* correspond to the Riemann sums that I was working with.  An MSE contributor gave me the heads up -- and showed that my corresponding "Riemann integrals" actually had values *different* from the sums.  But I used the same "rules" as I did with this current problem statement.  Apparently, it was incorrect.  So, I just want to know whether I have converted this sum to an integral  correctly.

Comment: Note that $\displaystyle lim_{n->\infty}$ is not a conventionally correct way of typesetting this notation, but $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}$ is. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Ok, got it - I will keep that in mind.  Thanks @MichaelHardy.

Comment: looks fine to me

Comment: Looks fine. Was the other integral improper? That could make thing complicate.

Comment: Hi, @user251257, does (m/n) have to be "small"?  For example, does it have to be less than 1, in order for me to convert it to the continuous variable x?  Thanks,

Comment: And yes, I believe that other integral might have been an improper one.  I'll try to look back at my previous questions to find it and review it, @user251257...

Comment: If you integrate over $[a, b]$, you just need a sequence of partitions of $[a,b]$ that get arbitrarily fine (like in the definition of Riemann integral).

Comment: Ok got it -- thanks so much @user251257 :-)